# SQL query to select rows from two table with some matching filters

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Data in my table like below.

I need SQL query which display my expected output from above two tables.

**holidayMaster**

```
 id     Date
 1     12-04-2015
```

**Customer table**

```
Name    startingdate     coupondate
A       12-03-2015      11-04-2015
A       12-03-2015      11-05-2015
A       12-03-2015      11-06-2015
A       12-03-2015      11-07-2015
A       12-03-2015      11-08-2015
A       12-03-2015      11-09-2015

B       13-03-2015      12-04-2015
B       13-03-2015      12-05-2015
B       13-03-2015      12-06-2015
B       13-03-2015      12-07-2015
B       13-03-2015      12-08-2015
B       13-03-2015      12-09-2015

C       14-03-2015      13-04-2015
C       14-03-2015      13-05-2015
C       14-03-2015      13-06-2015
C       14-03-2015      13-07-2015
C       14-03-2015      13-08-2015
C       14-03-2015      13-09-2015
```

**FOR EX** - In above customer table..there are 18 distinct rows ok, because coupondate are different in all rows.

Suppose user select coupondate from 01-04-2015 to 31-04-2015 ,so query display name,startingdate, coupondate, and all days between selected filter 
from 01-04 to 31-04.

And display name, startingdate, coupondate and 1 below all days with total.

And condition is if some days between selected days are available in holiday master then display - - - - -  to all days not 1.

In below output **12-04-2015 is available in holiday master ...so this display  - - - -  below all days..**

**Expected Output**

```
name   startingdate  coupondate  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  Total

A      12-03-2015     11-04-2015 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      31
B      13-03-2015     12-04-2015 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
C      13-03-2015     13-04-2015 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      31
```

Comment: I assume 1..31 are the days of month, is that correct?

Comment: yes this are all the days....

Comment: hi bodo is it possible for you to create above query.....

Comment: Sorry, I've no spare time right now. Do you need to solve this issue inside the database? It seems to be easier to query for the ranges and process then. I also don't get the point of your question. Should the days from 1 to 31 be marked as one if they are in the range of the coupon start date to end date, ignoring the month? what is with a coupon running from Februar 20th to March 19th? And where is the use of your table holidayMaster? I can't figure out where you need it in the below table

Comment: possible duplicate of [php code or sql query to get filtered data based on two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218459/php-code-or-sql-query-to-get-filtered-data-based-on-two-tables)

Comment: It looks like the duplicate of this question (asked two hours after this one) has a bit more information, so I propose to close this one. Please only ask questions once.