# php code or sql query to get filtered data based on two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Two table..

Data in my table like below...

I need sql query which display my expected output from above two tables...

**holidayMaster**

```
  id     Date
   1     12-04-2015
```

Customer table

```
 Name    startingdate     coupondate
 A       12-03-2015      11-04-2015
 A       12-03-2015      11-05-2015
 A       12-03-2015      11-06-2015
 A       12-03-2015      11-07-2015
 A       12-03-2015      11-08-2015
 A       12-03-2015      11-09-2015

 B       13-03-2015      12-04-2015
 B       13-03-2015      12-05-2015
 B       13-03-2015      12-06-2015
 B       13-03-2015      12-07-2015
 B       13-03-2015      12-08-2015
 B       13-03-2015      12-09-2015

 C       14-03-2015      13-04-2015
 C       14-03-2015      13-05-2015
 C       14-03-2015      13-06-2015
 C       14-03-2015      13-07-2015
 C       14-03-2015      13-08-2015
 C       14-03-2015      13-09-2015
```

FOR EX - In above customer table..there are 18 distinct rows ok..Bcoz coupondate are different in all rows.

Suppose user select coupondate from 01-04-2015 to 31-04-2015 ,so query display name,startingdate, coupondate, and all days between selected filter from 01-04 to 31-04.

and display name,startingdate, coupondate and 1 below all days with total.

and condition is if some days between selected days are available in holiday master then display - - - - - to all days not 1.

In below output 12-04-2015 is available in holiday master ...so this display - - - - below all days..

**All 1..31 are the days of Selected month.**

plz help to make sql query...

```
 SELECT CE.* FROM customer CE LEFT JOIN holidaymaster HM ON CE.coupondate = HM.date WHERE CE.created BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate AND CE.coupondate not in (select date from holidaymaster)
```

**Expected Output**

```
 name   startingdate  coupondate  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  Total

 A      12-03-2015     11-04-2015 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      31
 B      13-03-2015     12-04-2015 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 C      13-03-2015     13-04-2015 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      31
```

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: actually  i does not have enough knowledge of sql...so i cannot able to decide what to do to display 1 1 1 1 1 1 by default below all days...in every row...

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.